# bind custom object and view in the LinkedList or other container

Tags: android, listview, linked-list, containers, android-arrayadapter

I have my own class Order with many fields in it. I put LinkedList of them to the ListView with the custom ArrayAdapter. But I need to bind each order object with corresponding View of listView. I tried to implement getChildView() method of the listView but it doesn't work properly for me. Tell me please how can I implement robust and fast solution for this? SHould I use LinkedList for this? Or should I create my own data container? Besides, adding one more View field to the Order object seems to me like perfomance decreasing.

Comment: Would you pls post your attempt?

Comment: I've solved this issue. Posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by HashMap using. I use singletone pattern for hashmap creating and using:

```
    public class OrdersViewMapSingletone {
     Map<Order, View>  arrayList;

    private static OrdersViewMapSingletone instance;

    private OrdersViewMapSingletone()
    {
        arrayList = new  HashMap<Order,View>();
    }

    public static OrdersViewMapSingletone getInstance(){

        return instance;
    }

     public static void initInstance()
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
                instance = new OrdersViewMapSingletone();
         }
      }

    public Map<Order, View> getOrderViewMap()
    {
        return arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {       
    return getOrderViewMap().toString();    
    }
}
```

and in my OrderAdapter:

```
 Map<Order, View> orderViewMap = OrdersViewMapSingletone.getInstance().getOrderViewMap();
```

add items in the getView() method:

```
orderViewMap.put(order,row);
```

and this method for getting items in the activity:

```
public View getMapedView(Order order)
    {
        return this.orderViewMap.get(order);
    }
```

worked good for me. Perfomance is much better than ArrayList using.